# How do I insert a heading above the current one in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'm currently running Spacemacs+evil and pressing `C-RET` calls `evil-org-org-insert-heading-respect-content-below`, which inserts a a heading **below** the current one.

I couldn't find a dual/mirror command that would create a heading **above** the current one, though. Is there one, or what's a good implementation that does this?

---

Note: I'm self-answering with my solution, which is **the first elisp I've ever written** and is very tied to Spacemacs+evil, but I would love it if others could chime in with snippets that don't depend on Spacemacs nor evil and are as such more useful to the general org-mode user. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Building on kbdluv's answer, here's a simpler generic version that doesn't require evil-mode:

```
(defun org-insert-heading-above ()
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (org-insert-heading))
```

I've bound it to `C-o` (normally `open-line`) for org-mode files:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-o") 'org-insert-heading-above)))
```

Answer (score 2):

M-x org-insert-heading (usually bound to M-ret) will insert a heading above the current heading, and with a prefix arg below the current heading.

Comment: It will insert a heading above the current heading iff you are at the beginning of the line. There might be interactions with the setting of `org-M-RET-may-split-line` though.

Comment: @Nick exactly. My answer actually calls `org-insert-heading`, but first calls `evil-digit-argument-or-evil-org-beginning-of-line` to go to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that *works for me*. It is unfortunately very coupled to evil-mode (and to Spacemacs, if you consider the keybindings.)

I define a function which does the same as pressing `0,iha`, then bind it to `,b`.

I also bind the original `evil-org-org-insert-heading-respect-content-below` to `,f` so that the `,b`/`,f` pair uses the "backwards/forwards" mnemonic.

```
(defun my-org/insert-heading-above ()
  "Same as 0 , i h"
  (interactive)
  (evil-digit-argument-or-evil-org-beginning-of-line)
  (org-insert-heading)
  (evil-append 1))

(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode "f" 'evil-org-org-insert-heading-respect-content-below)
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode "b" 'my-org/insert-heading-above))
```

Comment: Another limitation of this solution is that it only works if the point is on the heading (the line starting with the `***`s). If it is *within* a heading (like in text written inside it), it turns the current _line_ into a heading instead of inserting a heading above the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kdbluv @steve-simms . I'm using Spacemacs on macOS and utilize `⌘return` to insert new heading below and `⌃⌘return` to insert new heading above (respect content) in both normal mode and then switch to insert mode.

```lisp
(defun my-org-insert-heading-below ()
  "Insert heading below and switch to insert mode."
  (interactive)
  (org-insert-heading-respect-content)
  (evil-insert-state 1))
(defun my-org-insert-heading-before ()
  "Insert heading above current heading and switch to insert mode."
  (interactive)
  (cond
   ((org-on-heading-p) nil)
   (t                  (org-backward-heading-same-level 0)))
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (org-insert-heading)
  (evil-insert-state 1))

(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
 (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<s-return>") 'my-org-insert-heading-below)
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<s-return>") 'my-org-insert-heading-below)
 (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<C-s-return>") 'my-org-insert-heading-before)
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<C-s-return>") 'my-org-insert-heading-before)
)
```